# Oracle apex button translation

Tags: oracle-apex

Hi is there any way of translating buttons like "Create" , "Edit" on forms in Apex. I already try to do that through message translation.

Answer (score 0):

If the language you need for the app is supported, you just need to specify the primary language. Take in mind that APEX runtime engine supports a number of languages:

> The Oracle APEX runtime engine which is used by developers to create applications is available in the following languages: Arabic, Brazilian Portuguese, Croatian, Czech, Danish, Dutch, Finnish, French, French - Canada, German, Greek, Hebrew, Hungarian, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Norwegian, Polish, Portuguese (Portugal) (pt), Romanian, Russian, Serbian - Cyrillic, Serbian - Latin, Simplified Chinese, Slovak, Slovenian, Spanish, Swedish, Thai, Traditional Chinese, and Turkish.

Please see [About Installing Translated Versions of Oracle APEX](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/22.1/htmig/installing-translated-versions-of-apex.html#GUID-D14592D7-CB4C-411B-B1AB-724FCEE22BEF) and [Specifying the Primary Language for an Application](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/22.1/htmdb/specifying-the-primary-language-for-application.html)

Also, your apps can support multiple languages. Please see [Understanding the Translation Process](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/22.1/htmdb/understanding-the-translation-process.html#GUID-50AFFADA-E439-4738-A072-F1ACB402AD85)

[image]

Comment: the OP's question was specifically about button label translations - how are those translated ? Are they included in the "Seed translatable text" process ? The documentation does not mention that.

Comment: yes, i found ineractive grid and reports menu translations, bit cant find buttons

Comment: @Octavarium, which language are you trying to use for your APEX app?

Comment: @MónicaGodoy Croatian

Comment: In this case, you need to translate the label buttons using the Translation Repository.
Go to App > Shared Components > Translate > Translation Repository.
Look for the label button.

Please see this guide: Understanding the Translation Process.